# Is there any way to run a custom js script in a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-console

Is there any way to run a custom js script in a browser? I check some values on a site and fix them. Usually, I do it manually but I wrote js script which allows me to do it in an automatic way partially. I am looking for a way to run this script via hotkeys or using browser extension instead of ctrl+v in a browser console.

Comment: Google gave me this: https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399

Comment: The answer is in the tags you've used :) A chrome extension can manipulate the contents of a page and it can also be triggered by a shortcut key.

Comment: Is this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en what you looking for?

Comment: Without add-on you can already save some snippets in the "Sources" tab of the dev console in Chrome (F2 - "Sources" - "New Snippet" - ...etc).

Comment: There are also [userscripts](https://greasyfork.org/en). They are the smaller versions of browser extensions but are more cross-compatible. Also, usually a lot less sophisticated because they are faster to develop. You could also save the script as a [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). It's a bookmark that runs a script when used, instead of redirecting you.

Comment: Thanks to you all. I think Tampermonkey is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bookmarklet, but you would need to click instead of pressing a key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).